# Nest JS Upload file, body is null

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

Hi guys Im using **NestJS**, and trying to upload Image file to server, with my request body...

But everytime I post data to server the image is null.

I use **NEST JS file interceptor** and everything from docs but it is not working ??

Im using Vue-bootstrap on Frontend & Nest JS on backend

Before posting data to Backend, my object looks like this:

```
icon: { File
name: "ScreenShot.png"
lastModified: 1585642001136
lastModifiedDate: Tue Mar 31 2020 10:06:41 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}
webkitRelativePath: ""
size: 53284
type: "image/png"
__proto__: File
},
name: "Test"
```

But when I console.log it on backend it is null,

```
   @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('icon', 1, { dest: 'tmp' }))
    async createData(
        @UploadedFiles() file: MulterFile[], @Body() data
    ) {
        console.log('Data');
        console.log(file); // this is null

        console.log(data); // this only contains name property, icon is null  like this { icon: null, name: "Test" }
    }
```

Does any one know what could be the problem ??? Why am I getting null value from File object ??

Answer (score 0):

Found issue I had to use this as request body :

```
const icon // my icon file
 const form = new FormData();
form.append('icon', icon);

request('patch', { url: `create`, data: form });
```